# How to find a tablefooter in jQuery without inner Table?

Tags: jquery

I have 1 main table, called `LsTable`.
Then I have X under tables which are generated dynamically called "`LsTablePos111`" (Number is dynamic)
Every Table has ofc a `<tfoot>.`

When I do `$("#LsTable Tfoot")` I will get all `TFoot`, because the `TFoot` of the inner tables are within the `LsTable`!

So how do I make sure I only get the Main-Table-TFoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is below

```
<table id="LsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>[LsTablePos100]<td>
       <td>[LsTablePos100]<td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>

   <tfoot>
     [something you want]
   </tfoot>

</table>
```

try this.

```
$("#LsTable > Tfoot")
```

[jquery child selector reference](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/#entry-examples)